# How do I fix the failed task in dag of Airflow

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I'm new to the Airflow and just tried to do an easy data transformation in the DAG for practice. However, I'm not sure why the first task always failed unexpectedly. Can someone give me some tips for how to debug the failed task in DAG or point the wrong part out?  much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import airflow
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta



def transform_data(*args, **kwargs):

    df = pd.read_csv("C:/aws-airflow/data.csv")
    df['element'] = df['element'].str.slice(2).str.replace('-', ",")

    df.to_csv("C:/aws-airflow/data_new.csv")

default_args = {
    'owner' : 'airflow',
    'start_date' : datetime(2021, 9, 1),
    'retries' : 0,
    'retry_delay' : timedelta(minutes = 2)


With DAG(
    dag_id = 'data_pipeline',
    schedule_interval = "@daily",
    default_args = default_args
) as dag:


    transform_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id = "transform_data",
        python_callable = transform_data
    )
    
    task_end = DummyOperator(
        task_id = 'none'
    )
    transform_date >> task_end
```

Comment: Can you share the error message?

Comment: There’s no error message. It just shows the first task failed. So, I just wonder to know how should I get the reason of the first task failed? Thanks

Comment: Try different variable name than `transform_data`. You have both Airflow task variable with this name and also method. I think param for python_callable is ambiguous, maybe passing wrong one.

Comment: It wouldn't work after renaming the function as others. :(

Comment: @Jammy Can you setup logging? And use try and except in your python methods.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues in your code.

1. You have rename your python function to have a different name that the operator object. Let's call it transform_data_fn.
2. When you are defining the task dependencies, you have a typo. `transform_data` instead of `transform_date`.

I took your code as it was, and changed the 2 mistakes:

```
import pandas as pd
from airflow import DAG

from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def transform_data_fn(*args, **kwargs):

    df = pd.read_csv("data/data.csv")
    df["element"] = df["element"]

    df.to_csv("data/data_new.csv")


default_args = {
    "owner": "airflow",
    "start_date": datetime(2021, 9, 1),
    "retries": 0,
    "retry_delay": timedelta(minutes=2),
}


with DAG(
    dag_id="data_pipeline", schedule_interval="@daily", default_args=default_args
) as dag:

    transform_data = PythonOperator(
        task_id="transform_data", python_callable=transform_data_fn, dag=dag
    )

    task_end = DummyOperator(task_id="none")

    transform_data >> task_end
```

NOTE: I'm not doing any transformation in the dataframe as it is irrelevant to the code itself. Also, because I didn't know how your csv file looks like.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. I just found the log and read the error message that it states " No such file or directory". I ran the airflow in the docker compose, and is there any way to get the path correctly?  Thanks

Comment: Place you data.csv file inside the ```data``` folder that is at the same level than the ```dags ``` folder.